# Magento 2 Shipping tracker

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Product is not compatible with Page Builder - Version 2.0.8 claims to be compatible with Page Builder, but the zip file does not support this claim

Any help for this??

Comment: Please provide more details such as Magento version, steps to reproduce the error and error messages. Also, Magento related questions will probably get better response in https://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @kiatng There is not many details provided about the error, and there is also this question provided in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350639/magento-2-marketplace-extension-submission-issue-product-is-not-compatible-wi